# Cannot find local database on WPF project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a WPF application for a client and a SQL server is required. I am currently using Visual Studio to develop everything, but I have never used SQL servers outside of web application before. I add a new SQL database to my WPF project by adding a "Service-based Database", and everything works fine. Until I transfer the project over to a different computer where it crashes and gives me the error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Database not found". Is there something that I'm missing about setting up a database inside my VS project? Why does it only work on my development PC and not any other that I transfer it to?

The code that it crashes on:

```
string cn_string = Properties.Settings.Default.connection_String;
//Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\_data\db_local.mdf;Integrated Security=True
string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Clients";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn_string))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("tbl_Clients");
   sda.Fill(dt);
   MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Sorry for my easy questions, I am currently learning programming in high-school. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: My guess is that you currently actually have sql server installed on your machine where you are doing development. When you migrate the project to another computer, that computer probably doesn’t have sql server installed, hence the error about not being able to find the database. I would suggest looking at using SQLite since it is a file based database that you could distribute with your WPF app

Comment: @TimRobinson That's what I thought at first, and I checked to see if I have any kind of SQL server installed on my dev PC - and I don't. When I add the `service-based database` to my WPF project in VS, it creates a `.mdf` file, is this a database file?

Comment: you still need to install SQL Server LocalDB on client.

Comment: @vasily.sib But I don't even have it installed on my dev PC, so how was I able to run and develop the application if it's required to have SQL Server LocalDB?

Comment: .mdf files are database files for sql server. I’m still guessing that part of your visual studio installation installs sql server of some sort on your development machine and that that installation isnt on the new computer you move the files to. Sql server isn’t really meant to be a portable database that you would distribute along with an application. That’s what SQLite is for

Comment: @LachlanMather, you install it with Visual Studio

Comment: @TimRobinson O.K. thanks for explaining it to me. I didn't realise that VS also installed SQL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017#install-localdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a service-based database requires you to set up a SQL Server service on the machine where you intend to run the WPF client application.

If you want an embedded database that you can xcopy deploy with your application, you should take a look at [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). It is, unlike the service-based database that you create in Visual Studio, completely self-contained and doesn't require you to install any service.